# A box contains 5 balls numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. The probability that the sum of obtained two numbers is even.

Tags: probability

The solution states the probability that the sum of obtained two numbers is even equals = $\frac{3\choose{2}}{5\choose{2}}+\frac{1}{5\choose{2}}$.

I didn't understand this solution. I know that if the first ball is odd there's a 0.6 chance of the second ball giving an even sum and if the first ball is even then it's 0.4. How can I get this probability. I know that sample space is $C(5,2)$ because it is the every possibility that we can choose 2 balls. But I couldn't understand the top parts. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\binom{5}{2}$ possible pairs and the sum is even if we choose the unique pair $(2,4)$ or two odd pairs that is $\binom{3}{2}$, therefore

$$P(\text{even sum})=\frac{\binom{3}{2}+1}{\binom{5}{2}}$$

Comment: Do you know how can we solve this with conditional probability way? Like, P(even | given 1st is even)+P(even | given 1st is odd)?

Comment: @70pr4k We have that 

$$P(\text{first even} \mid \text{sum even}) =\frac25\cdot \frac14$$

$$P(\text{first odd} \mid \text{sum even})=\frac35\cdot \frac24$$